# PDF Signature Panel Display

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

What is the difference between the two pdf?

PDF_1

[image]

and

PDF_2

[image]

The first picture pdf signature is **valid**?

Comment: The first signature is a certification signature, the second one an approval signature. Both look valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is copied from the book [PDF and digital signatures](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures):

[image]

*Figure 2.17: Ordinary (approval) and Certification (author) signature*

ISO-32000-1 specifies that a PDF document may contain the following standard types of signatures:

- One or more approval signatures— these signatures appear in signature
  form fields. The  upper left document in figure 2.17 is an example of
  such a signature. Adobe Reader shows a  green check mark when a valid
  approval signature is present.
- At most one certification signature— this signature can define
  different permissions, as  shown in figure 2.17. You’ll see a blue
  ribbon when a document was certified.
- At most two usage rights signatures— these are signatures created
  using a private key that is  proprietary for instance to Adobe. When
  a PDF document is signed with a usage rights  signature using Adobe’s
  key, the document is Reader enabled. Adobe Reader will unlock 
  certain usage rights, for instance allowing you to save a filled out
  form locally. Other vendors  can use their private key to enforce
  similar usage rights. This type of signature is outside the scope of
  this paper.